# Error when defining variables in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I just started to learn about Pyomo. In several tutorials it is stated that the command for creating a variable is just `model.Variable = VAR(...)`. However, I get the error message when using the Var function:

> ```
> NameError: name 'Var' is not defined
> ```

Why do I get this error? Here you see my full code (the problematic statement is the last line):

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Sets


#empty set
model.A = pyo.Set()

#initialized set with values
model.D = pyo.Set(initialize=['red', 'green', 'blue'])


#Define a function to create ta sequence of numbers
def createSequenceOfNumbers(startNumber, endNumber):
    return (i for i in range (startNumber, endNumber + 1))

model.C = pyo.Set(initialize=createSequenceOfNumbers(4, 9))
model.E = pyo.RangeSet(5,9)


#printing a set
model.C.pprint()
model.D.pprint()
model.E.pprint()


#Parameter

#define sets
model.A_P = pyo.RangeSet(1,3)
model.B_P = pyo.RangeSet(1,3)

#Values for the sets by using a dict-datatype.
valuesForParam = {}
valuesForParam [1,1] = 1
valuesForParam [1,3] = 2
valuesForParam [2,3] = 10

#define Parameters (2 dimensional)
model.P = pyo.Param(model.A_P, model.B_P, initialize=valuesForParam, default=0)

model.P.pprint()



#Variables


model.variable1 = Var(within=NonNegativeReals, bounds =(0,6), initialize=1.5)
```

Comment: Use `pyo.Var` instead of just `Var`

Comment: Thanks Stradivari for your comment. When I use your suggested code I get the following error message "NameError: name 'NonNegativeReals' is not defined"

Comment: Please prepend pyo when using its variables. `pyo.NonNegativeReals`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Stradivari. Now it is okay :-). However, I do not understand, why I always have to use pyo before the commands in this case while in all tutorials they do not use it? By the way: If you write your comments in an answer, I will accept and upvote it such that you get points for that. Anyways, thanks a lot for your good help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just importing the `pyomo.environ` module while the tutorials probably use the `from` syntax.

These variables are inside `pyomo.environ` so you have 3 alternatives:

1. Import them explicitly `from pyomo.environ import Var, NonNegativeReals`
2. Import them using a wildcard `from pyomo.environ import *` (this is considered an antipattern)
3. Import the module (with an alias in this case) `import pyomo.environ as pyo` and access them like `pyo.VariableName`

PS: this isn't really related to pyomo. For more information about the python import system please read: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stradivari. What would you say is the most common way in Python for importing (which of your 3 suggested options)?

Comment: Using wildcard is frowned upon because you cant see what you are importing. I usually just follow the "convention" for each library, for pyomo I think the most common way is the third.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Stradivari. But when using the wildcard you are importing everything, right? This way you know what you are importing. It is just everything and thus you do not have to care about specific moduels.

Comment: If you search "python wildcard import" in google there should be multiple posts about why you should avoid them, I would say that for small (non production) code it isn't a issue

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it.